# check for occurance of a particular value in every columns of a dataframe in r

Tags: r, dataframe, for-loop, multiple-columns

I have a DF with student_id & day

```
student_id  day_1   day_2   day_3   day_4   day_5   day_6   day_7   day_8
A_0001      P   P   P   A   P   L   P   P
B_0001      A   P   P   P   P   P   L   P
C_0001      P   P   P   P   P   P   A   P
A_0002      P   P   P   P   P   P   P   L
A_0003      P   P   L   P   P   P   P   P
A_0005      P   P   P   P   P   A   P   P
B_0002      P   P   P   P   L   L   P   P
B_0004      P   P   P   P   L   A   P   P
B_0005      P   P   P   P   P   P   L   P
```

Here P is present, A absent and L is Leave
I want to create a column in the end a count only absent A values for each student.

I have tried using for loop but getting error

Answer (score 0):

You could use `rowSums` like this:

```r
library(dplyr)
df %>%
  mutate(total_A = rowSums(. == 'A'))
#>   student_id day_1 day_2 day_3 day_4 day_5 day_6 day_7 day_8 total_A
#> 1     A_0001     P     P     P     A     P     L     P     P       1
#> 2     B_0001     A     P     P     P     P     P     L     P       1
#> 3     C_0001     P     P     P     P     P     P     A     P       1
#> 4     A_0002     P     P     P     P     P     P     P     L       0
#> 5     A_0003     P     P     L     P     P     P     P     P       0
#> 6     A_0005     P     P     P     P     P     A     P     P       1
#> 7     B_0002     P     P     P     P     L     L     P     P       0
#> 8     B_0004     P     P     P     P     L     A     P     P       1
#> 9     B_0005     P     P     P     P     P     P     L     P       0
```

<sup>Created on 2023-03-09 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>